# PHP AJAX not updating dynamically eventhough consolelog has the correct values

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to update $_POST['category'] with the click of a button. I'm trying to use AJAX (for the first time) to achieve this as read on multiple other pages here. My JS function currently updates the correct value in the console however it fails to actually update the POST to the correct value or at least that is wat I am assuming. I need help trying to get the value to POST so I can utilize it in PHP as a value.

**MAIN PHP FILE**

```
<div class="subcategory text_markup_subtitle">
    <ul>
        <li class="subhead" value="mobiliteit" onClick="subCat(event)">Mobiliteit</li></a>
        <li class="subhead" value="kracht" onClick="subCat(event)">Kracht</li>
        <li class="subhead" value="uithouding" onClick="subCat(event)">Uithouding</li>
        <li class="subhead" value="stretching" onClick="subCat(event)">Stretching</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**INCLUDE PHP FILE**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php  
        $_POST['category'] = '';
        var_dump($_POST['category'])
?>
```

**JS FILE**

```
function cat(event){
    var values = $(event.target).attr('value')
    console.log(values);

    $.ajax({
        url: "Videos.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { category: values },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('succes');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your AJAX request will send a new request to Videos.php. Any data you send will be available in _that one instance_ of that specific script. Remember, PHP only runs when you make HTTP request to the server, and also remember POST values don't persist across different requests. It's not clear precisely what else you're expecting it to update, or where that is located in your code. Is `var_dump($_POST['category'])` part of videos.php? Change your ajax success callback to `success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }` and then you can see what PHP returned

Comment: The goal is eventually to utilize the newly updated POST to display relevant videos (in videos.php) based on the value of the li in the main file. So I’ll utilize $_POST as one of the SQL selectors. As for the setting POST to blank at the start is simply because else I get an error that POST isn’t set. I’ll also use this to display all videos at the start. Before people filter down based on their clicks in the list

Comment: Ok. Well, You can use that posted value to run your SQL query and get back some results. That data is then returned (if you echo it) to the AJAX call into the `response` variable in the "success" callback. From there you need to write some JavaScript to update your page

Comment: ?? No, that isn't what I said. I think maybe you need to go and study some ajax tutorials etc because I don't think you have grasped the core concept yet

Comment: I haven’t grasped it yet and documentation isn’t helping me understand kt either. The posted value doesn’t really work since I can’t get it to even display with echo? How would SQL work if echo doesn’t?

Comment: Echo does work. But, as i explained above, the content which php echoed is sent into a javascript variable, not directly into your page.  Remember this is a background, asynchronous request. During an ajax request, the page you're already showing will stay exactly as it was. It will only change if you specifically write some JavaScript code inside the "success" function which makes changes to the page, perhaps by using the data which php had echoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue with the help of ADyson. (Thanks my man). I added the following code $("#showmessageID").show().HTML(result) so that the div with id showmessageID updates each time on succession.

The div on my main PHP file which has the include videos.php received the ID showmessageID as to update it each time the AJAX call succeeds.

**Main PHP file**

```
<div class="action_container" id="showmessageID">
<?php  include "videos.php"; ?>            
</div>
```

**JS file**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/exercise/Videos.php",
    type: "post",
    data: { category: category_SQL },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#showmessageID").show().html(data)
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

**Video.php**

```
echo $_POST['category']
```